# Python: Get all values from like keys in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of dictionaries:

```
original_data = [{"id":1, "other_fields":"other_data"},{"id":2, "other_fields":"other_data"},{"id":3, "other_fields":"other_data"}]
```

I need to be able to do get the values of all of the "id" keys and add them into a new list of dictionaries:

`new_data = [{"id":1, "processed_data":"processed data"}]`

Adding to or replacing anything in the original list of dictionaries is not an option.
It will be working with a rather large list.

Comment: It's not at all clear how `new_data` is derived from `original_data`. Why is there only one value (`1`) from the `"id"` keys? Where does `"processed_data"` come from?

Comment: Hi (it's important),

I try to answer to your post but I don't understand what is your question ?
When you say "get the values of all of the "id" keys", what represent the processed_data ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can try below to filter for what is needed

```
original_data = [{"id":1, "other_fields":"other_data1"},{"id":2, "other_fields":"other_data2"},{"id":3, "other_fields":"other_data3"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(original_data)
print(df)

   id other_fields
0   1  other_data1
1   2  other_data2
2   3  other_data3
```

The keys are

```
list(df['id'])

[1, 2, 3]
```

The values are

```
list(df['other_fields'])

['other_data1', 'other_data2', 'other_data3']
```

Answer (score 1):

For loop:

```py
new_data = []

for data in original_data:
    new_data.append({"id": data["id"], "processed_data": "processed_data"})
```

One-liner:

```py
new_data = [{"id": data["id"], "processed_data": "processed_data"} for data in original_data]
```